# Issue with Drupal-7 Editor

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor

I have a problem with Drupal7's text editor.
I put an image inside my texts (By CKEditor), and set some styles to the image (For example width or height), and save the post, when I back to edit the post, the styles gone and my image rolls back to the default width and height!

See the issue here:

[image]

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the very same problem. I have already removed all HTML filters etc

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that these images will actually also be rendered (when viewing the page), make sure that the "text format" used in the node does allow the img-tag. Typically for a node using the "Filtered HTML", it could well be that the img-tag is not allowed (yet) as one of the available HTML tags. In that case, your HTML code does include an 'img" tag, but when viewing the saved node the image is not rendered (visible). To resolve it, within admin you must enter the img-tag as one of the allowed HTML tags for the text format used in the node.

And if the img-tag is already allowed in the filter you're using, then it must be some other tag that is not yet allowed.